# Why doesn't DictWriter.writerow write anything to the csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to write some data into a csv file. But nothing was written except the header, which is words and number. What's wrong with my code?

Here is my code.

```
import os
import csv

csvFile = open('Trail.csv','w+')
fieldname = ['words', 'number']
trialDict = {'apple':1, 'banana':4, 'cat':6}
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldname, extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(trialDict)
csvFile.close()
```

I get want you mean and I modify my code. But there is still a problem.

```
import os
import csv

csvFile = open('Trail.csv','w+')
fieldname = ['words', 'number']
trialDict = {'words':'apple', 'number':5, 'words':'banana','number':6, 'words':'cat', 'number':5}
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldname, extrasaction='ignore') writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(trialDict)
csvFile.close()
```

The output becomes:

```
word numbers
cat   5
```

How can I write everything into the file? I tried the `writerows` function, but it returned the error:

```
str object has no attribute get()
```

Comment: What were you expecting that to do? None of the keys in `trialDict` is `'words'` or `'number'`.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?

Answer (score 1):

The real issue here is that you are overwriting your keys with TrialDict and it is only taking the last two instances of `words` and `number`.

```
>>> trialDict = {'words':'apple', 'number':5, 'words':'banana','number':6, 'words':'cat', 'number':5}
>>> trialDict
{'words': 'cat', 'number': 5}
```

What you want to do is have a dictionary of count by word altogether and just write the key,value pairs :

```
fieldnames = ['words', 'number']
trialDict = {'apple': 5, 'banana': 6, 'cat': 5}

with open("Trial.csv", "w+") as f:
    f.write(','.join(fieldnames) + '\n')
    for word, number in trialDict.items():
        f.write(word + ',' + str(number) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names are headers, you should include keys in your dict corresponding to your headers, if this is your requirement, this code should work:

```
import os 
import csv

csvFile = open('Trail.csv','w+')
fieldname = ['apple', 'banana', 'cat']
trialDict = {'apple':1, 'banana':4, 'cat':6}
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldname, extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(trialDict)

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the header/fieldnames to be `word` and `number`. This solution does not get you that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `DictWriter` for this.  The standard `writer` works.  Also note the `newline=''` parameter when opening the file as per [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv

fieldname = ['words', 'number']
trialDict = {'apple':1, 'banana':4, 'cat':6}

with open('Trail.csv','w',newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(fieldname)
    for key,value in trialDict.items():
        writer.writerow([key,value])
```

Output:

```
words,number
apple,1
banana,4
cat,6
```

To use `DictWriter` you need a list of dictionaries that have keys that are the header values:

```
import csv

fieldname = ['words', 'number']
trialList = [{'words':'apple','number':1},
             {'words':'banana','number':4},
             {'words':'cat','number':6}]

with open('Trail.csv','w',newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile,fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(trialList)
```